# Web3j: buying a token

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

If I have an ERC20 contract on my blockchain, and a user wants to buy tokens as in the following scenario:

1. User gives the number of tokens they want to buy
2. An info box will popup to show the user how many ether they will pay and the remaining balance
3. Once confirmed, a the amount of tokens in balance should be shown

To obtain tokens, I have to call a method in a smart contract which looks like this. `obtainTok(BigInteger weiValue)`

What is the formula to calculate the weiValue in this scenario using web3j?

**EDIT**
Since there is no Javadocs for the library the parameters are not really clear for me as a beginner.

```
ethGetBalance(String address, DefaultBlockParameter defaultBlockParameter)
```

Does the address here represent the wallet address or user address?

Comment: Are you asking for web3j (Java) or web3js (JavaScript)?

Comment: @AdamKipnis web3j. But I couldn't create a tag

Comment: The address is whatever you want to know the ether balance of. Both account addresses and contract addresses can hold ether. If you're holding all your assets in a wallet, then you use the wallet contract address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ReyHaynes answer is correct for web3js. If you are attempting to do this in web3j, you would use `org.web3j.utils.toWei(valueInEther, Unit.ETHER);` where `valueInEther` is a `String` or `BigDecimal`.

To expand on the answer, you wouldn't typically send ether to your smart contract as a parameter to `obtainTok()`. You would send it in as part of the transaction object and read it in your smart contract with `msg.value` (which is in Wei).

Comment: So no need for a formula like getting the price first then dividing it on the ethBalance? Also please check the edit I made to the question.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. If you want to show something like the maximum number of tokens a user can buy, you would divide the balance by the price. If you're executing the buy action in your smart contract, you would divide the amount sent to the contract (msg.value) by the price. Smart contracts always work at the Wei level, but both the web3j and web3js client APIs lets you send it in at whatever level you want. You just need to specify the correct unit.

Answer (score 2):

Web3 has a utility function called `toWei()`, you can use that to convert from any unit.

`web3.utils.toWei(number [, unit])`

In your case:

`web3.utils.toWei(ETHER_VALUE, 'ether')`

More info in the documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei